# How to cast a 1D array into columns of 2D array in FORTRAN at each iteration?

Tags: matrix, vector, fortran

I already spend a **full week** on this. But I couldn't solve it.

I want to cast a 1D array into column of 2D array in a loop. At 1st iteration the size of this 2D array is same as the 1D array. So. There should be no problem to cast it. At 2nd iteration, 1D array is going to have different elements. I want to cast it to 2nd column of 2D array. this continues and the algorithm is such that you can not guess the number of columns of 2D array to allocate it before starting calculation.

In Matlab one can use a do loop like this:

```
do iter=1:m
p(:,iter) = r
end
```

But how about FORTRAN? 
The below test codes are intended to show what I mean:

CODE 1: (USING POINTER)

```
program ptrtest

 real, pointer, CONTIGUOUS :: Mr(:)
 real, pointer, CONTIGUOUS :: Mp(:,:)
 real, DIMENSION(9) ::abc


 integer :: n = 2
 iter=3

 Do i=1,iter

 alpha2 = 2
 allocate(Mr(n**2))
 abc= 42

 Mr(1:n**2) = 0.5 * abc(1:n**2)
 write(*,*) 'Mr='
 write(*,555) Mr

 Mr(1:n**2) => Mp(1:n**2,1:1) 

 WRITE(*,*) 'Mp='
 WRITE(*,555) Mp

 end do

 555  FORMAT(F12.4,1X) 


 end program ptrtest
```

ERROR :

```
gfortran -Wall -o "1234" "1234.f95" (in directory: /home/vahid/Desktop)
1234.f95:26.15:
 Mr(1:n**2) => Mp(1:n**2,1:1)
               1
Error: Rank remapping target must be rank 1 or simply contiguous at (1)
Compilation failed.
```

CODE 2: (USING A SIMPLE LOOP)

```
program ptrtest

 real, pointer, CONTIGUOUS :: Mr(:)
 real, pointer, CONTIGUOUS :: Mp(:,:)
 real, DIMENSION(9) ::abc


 integer :: n = 2
 iter=3

 Do i=1,iter

 alpha2 = 2
 allocate(Mr(n**2))
 abc= 42

 Mr(1:n**2) = 0.5 * abc(1:n**2)
 write(*,*) 'Mr='
 write(*,555) Mr

 do j = 1, iter
    Mp(:, j) = Mr
 end do

 WRITE(*,*) 'Mp='
 WRITE(*,555) Mp

 end do

 555  FORMAT(F12.4,1X) 


 end program ptrtest
```

ERROR:

```
 Mr=
     21.0000
     21.0000
     21.0000
     21.0000

Program received signal SIGSEGV: Segmentation fault - invalid memory reference.

Backtrace for this error:
#0  0x7F1F888E4777
#1  0x7F1F888E4D7E
#2  0x7F1F8853CD3F
#3  0x400D67 in MAIN__ at 1234.f95:?
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what you mean. I tried it just the way you envisioned it:

```
program vec2mat
    implicit none
    integer :: r(3), m(3, 3), i

    r = (/ 1, 2, 3/)
    do i = 1, 3
        m(:, i) = r
    end do

    write(*, '(3I4)') m

end program vec2mat
```

And it works perfectly:

```
$ ./vec2mat
   1   2   3
   1   2   3
   1   2   3
```

(Except of course that the first index in a multi-dimensional array is the fastest changing.)

Okay, you have added a lot more information since I posted this:

`DATA` is depreciated. It still works, but without the brackets:

```
DATA r/1.1, 2, 3, 4/
```

But if you want to initialise `r` immediately, it's usually better practise to write it in the variable declaration:

```
REAL*8, DIMENSION(4) :: r = (/1.1, 2, 3, 4/)
```

In the actual code block, there is no need at all to use `DATA` (I'm not even sure it's allowed). Just go ahead and assign the values:

```
ALLOCATE r(4)
r = (/1.1, 2, 3, 4/)
```

(You have to allocate an allocatable array before you can write stuff to it.)

Finally, the `ALLOCATE` error seems weird:

```
ALLOCATE(p)
```

cannot work, because the program doesn't know how much space to allocate for `p`. But

```
ALLOCATE(p(1:4, 1:4))
```

Should work just fine.

And normally, the compiler would output the whole line that caused the error, and not abbreviate it to something other. So assuming that the `ALLOCATE` line hasn't changed, the only thing I can think of is that the late `DATA` (as far as I know, `DATA` should be part of the declaration block, and `ALLOCATE` is part of the instruction block, so `ALLOCATE` can never be before `DATA`) is messing things up.

Replace

```
DATA r(/1.1, 2, 3, 4/)
```

with

```
ALLOCATE(r(4))
r = (/1.1, 2, 3, 4/)
```

and you should be good to go.

Comment: thank you for the prompt reply. I have updated my code and included the errors as well. I couldn't solve the issue after your reply.

Comment: In my original code, I am getting the size of the "r" vector during the code. I can not specify the size at the beginning. That is the reason I am using a colon...

Comment: So the moment you know the size, you need to `allocate` r, and then assign the values.